# Notification socket server in python

Tags: python

I want to write a very basic python application which will listen on a tcp port.
When a client will connect to this server, i want the server to send notifications (a few bytes) to the client and detect if connexion has been closed by the client.

I do not want the client to send data. The client will be on a embedded device (wifi) and i want to preserve battery life.

1. I want to detect on the server if connexion with client is closed. (I suppose there are some handshakes in protocol stack that can tell me if link is active ?)
2. I want to be sure that socket.send is thread-safe. The send_notification method can be called by another thread. So if i send PING and NOTIFICATION at the same time, should the client receive something like PINOTIFICATIONNG for example ?

There is my source code:

```
import socket
import threading
import time

class ClientThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, manager, ip, port, clientsocket):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.manager = manager
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.clientsocket = clientsocket
        self.clientsocket.settimeout(1.0)

    def run(self):
        self.manager.clients.append(self)
        while True:
              try:
                    self.clientsocket.send("PING")
              except:
                 break
              time.sleep(5)

        self.manager.clients.remove(self)

    def send_notification(self):
        self.clientsocket.send("NOTIFICATION")

class Manager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = []
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.bg_task)
        thread1.start()

    def send_notification(self):
        for client in self.clients:
            client.send_notification()

    def bg_task(self):
        tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        tcpsock.bind(("",9008))

        while True:
            tcpsock.listen(10)
            (clientsocket, (ip, port)) = tcpsock.accept()
            newthread = ClientThread(self, ip, port, clientsocket)
            newthread.start()
```

Thanks

Comment: Likely for a server like this you don't need threads at all, if number of _simultaneous_ connections won't exceed few hundreds.

Comment: I need threads because i have a lot of events which can rise notifications

Comment: Then I'd suggest to take an instant framework. Python has built-in one [SocketServer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html) or, for example, check [Twisted framework](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tutorial/intro.html). In any case a proper framework decomposes connections/clients management and application business logic.